# How can I dynamically insert dates in dncalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I've got a problem using dncalendar, hope someone will help me!

I need a simple calendar in which being able to save and recover data from a db. dncalendar seemed good, but I have now problem in dynamically insert data into it.
I post some code for clarification. I recover the dates from some input fields called .date-smart and build an array (data_note). Problem is when I want to dynamically insert this dates into object notes, without knowing how many dates I have. If I do it like in below code, everything works fine, but I do not know how to do it with a for cycle or similar. Can someone help me?

```
var data_note =[];
var note = [];
$(".date-smart").each(function(){
   data_note.push($(this).val()) 
   note.push("SW");
})

var my_calendar = $("#dncalendar-container").dnCalendar({
    dataTitles: { defaultDate: 'default', today : 'Today' },
    startWeek:'monday',
});

my_calendar.build();
my_calendar.update({
    notes: [{'date': data_note[0], 'note':note[0]}, {'date': data_note[1], 'note':note[1]}];
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by cycle? does that mean, you want to update `notes` for `n` number of entries?

Comment: thanks for the reply. Yes, I mean I can have n entries in data_note and I have to populate object notes, but I am not able to do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't just make a variable feed all data in it and then pass it to notes

Like

```
var data_note =[];
var note = [];
var notesArr = [];

$(".date-smart").each(function(){
   data_note.push($(this).val()) 
   note.push("SW");
   notesArr.push({'date': $(this).val(), 'note': 'SW'});
})


var my_calendar = $("#dncalendar-container").dnCalendar({
    dataTitles: { defaultDate: 'default', today : 'Today' },
    startWeek:'monday',
});

my_calendar.build();
my_calendar.update({
    notes: notesArr
})
```

Comment: well.... first thing I tried... but gave me an error.... thought was something that I didn't understand about dncalendar... but since now works, probably just bad coding by me. Solved, very thanks for your time!

Comment: Glad it helped. Please mark it as a accepted answer, so that community gets to know this question is already resolved. :)